# VBA "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

Despite many hits, I have been unable to find an answer for my issue. I wrote a small routine to insert a formula after the last column of some data in a sheet.

My issue is that I am adding a formula and getting

> "Application-defined or object-defined error".

I take the formula directly from the worksheet where it returns a result and try to add it to a copy of the sheet. I have done this successfully with other formulas. Without going in to the routine, the line that gives the error is:

```
Range(Cells(headerRow + 1, lastCol).Address, Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-29],'[dataFile.xlsx]Report Page_1'!$A$2:$B$1475,2,FALSE), ""-"")"
```

It works if I remove the equal sign so that it is only adding text to the specified range. So the issue appears to be with the formula I am adding, but it does work when the formula is pasted in to the top cell and filled down the column. In the final version in the VBA it will use R1C1 format for relative references.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `FormulaR1C1` and then using `A2` as cell reference?

Comment: ...use `.Formula` instead

Comment: I updated it to RC[-29] as I am actually using R1C1 format.  I had pasted that part in to a separate test sub to get it working and had put "A2" there but it should have said RC[-29]. The error is still there though.

Comment: OK. I think I see the issue - will be checking now but I am not using R1C1 format for the absolute references in the data file. Thanks Luuklag. I am guessing that this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is fixed. I'll keep this in mind going forwards.

Comment: A couple points: 1) If you have more than one worksheet in this workbook, please add the worksheet reference before all `Range()` objects (including `Cells()`), e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet100").Range("A1")`.  2) You don't need the `.Address` after the `Cells()`

Comment: Welcome to SO. The best way to thank @Luuklag is to upvote his comment. Going forward, remember to mark accepted answers as such, etc.

Comment: Hello @Excelosaurus. I would love to upvote Luuklag but since he only posted a comment and not an answer there does not appear to me a mechanism for doing so. Please correct me if I am wrong.